# align controls left to right on a modal pop up in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I cant get my text boxes to align left to right in the Modal Pop up. Here is the code in the . What should i change.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="ModalPanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <!-- shadow container -->
                        <div class="shadowContainer">
                                <h1><asp:Label runat="server" id="xyz" Text="Make" /></h1>
                                <tr style="width:1000px;">
                                <td colspan = "2" style="width:100px;"> 
                                <div>Name1</div>
                                 <asp:TextBox  runat="server" id="Name1" MaxLength="40"/>
                                      <span id="Span1" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="Val1" runat="server"
                                            OnServerValidate="Val1_ServerValidate" ControlToValidate="Name1" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="thisGroup"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                      </span>   
                                 <div>Name2</div>  
                                  <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" MaxLength="40"/><br />
                                      <span  id="Span2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
                                            OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidateEmptyText="true" ValidationGroup="thisGroup"></asp:CustomValidator>
                                      </span>                                      
                                </td>
                            </tr>                                                

                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I modified the code from my earlier post. Also if there is a SAVE button on the modal pop up, how do i ensure that hitting the SAVE does not change the formatting of the alignment?

Comment: I am confused. Do you want all of the controls on one row? Also if you do not want the controls to move on save then you need to leave enough room for your Validator message to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have everything you need. The only problem I can see is that you do not have a width set for your td; therefore, it may not be created wide enough by default. Make sure you set it with a width that is large enough to contain all of the content.

```
<td colspan="2" style="width:500px;">
```

**Edit**:

I believe the problem is your width set on your td. Now that you have updated your code, I can see that you only have the td to have a set width of `100px`. This will cause the controls to break on separate lines.